# How often are SMP maps automatically saved?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I've found these two commands related to 'auto-save' on the [Op](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Op) wiki page:

- `/save-off` - turns off auto-save.
- `/save-on` - turns on auto-save.

but I can't find any documentation on the length of time between this 'auto-save'.

Is the duration between saves referenced anywhere?

I'm trying to automatically backup SMP saves and although I'm aware of some libraries where I can communicate with the server ([mcchat](https://github.com/charliesome/mcchat) for example) I'd rather use something that was built into the game as it reduces the chance of it breaking later.

<sub>Bonus points for diagrams.</sub>

Comment: I don't trust auto-save. I'm always manically "save-all"-ing so I don't lose my work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If our experience on Fosco's server is worth anything: by far *not frequently enough.* We've easily lost hours worth of work due to server crashes. :(

Comment: Aye, this was one the reasons I asked. I've seen some references to save-on thrashing the disk but it appears to not be the case

Comment: that might be related to this: http://www.minecraftforum.net/viewtopic.php?f=1013&t=82341

Comment: @Alex this also happened without hey0 enabled...

Comment: @Josh It's not a jab, poor Fosco doesn't have any responsibility with this.

Comment: Oh, OK. Well +1 for mentioning Fosco anyway ;-) (I really do need to get Minecraft so I can learn what the heck the rest of you are always talking about...)

Answer (score 5):

I actually wrote a script to handle starting, stopping, console commands, and auto-saving on my Linux servers. I then have a cronjob that issues a `save-all` command every hour and another that backs-up the world to remote storage every hour so i can restore when my dick friends mess stuff up. I can do stuff like this from a Linux shell:

```
$ minecraft_server stop
$ minecraft_server start
$ minecraft_server_command [any server command]
```

Also using this script, I wrote a web application that I can interactively give myself (or whoever) any number of a resource (i.e. >64 at a time).

I'd be happy to put it up on pastebin or something if somebody wanted it. It requires screen be installed and the web-app is written in python with a [django](http://www.djangoproject.com/) web framework and MySQL database so that would be kind of difficult to port.

Answer (score -1):

It Should be in your Bukkit.yml file it will say autosave: 0 thats the default. I prefer making it 6000 for 5 minutes

Comment: This question is about the Mojang server, not about the CraftBukkit server.